# Manually Loading Deferred slot/components in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I ran into an issue, my lazy loaded PDP module having issue with deferred loadingof componnets
I used **deferLoading: DeferLoadingStrategy.INSTANT** but didnt work.

actually,I want to scroll down to a slot by clicking on button in top of the screen, like for review/rating componnets from top to bottom scroll.

Can I load deferred slot/components using any service on button click ?

Answer (score 0):

`INSTANT` is the default deferred loading configuration. If you are specifically working on the review/rating component, you might want to look into the `above-the-fold loading`

More information can be found here - https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/above-the-fold/